# Ignore characters when sorting list of lists

Tags: python, function

Trying to create a function to filter out 'University of' from a list of university data in order to sort them alphabetically. This is the code I have so far:

```
def filter_list(uni):
for u in uni:
    for n in u:
      if n.startswith('University of the '):
        n = n[18:] + ' University'
      elif n.startswith('University of '):
        n = n[14:] + ' University'
    return uni
```

Expected output:

> ('Buckinghamshire New University', '78%', '39%', '82%', '0%', '0%', '52%'),
> ('Middlesex University', '82%', '48%', '80%', '57%', '75%', '54%'),
> ('City, University of London', '83%', '51%', '77%', '69%', '63%', '59%'),
> ('Goldsmiths, University of London',
> '85%',
> '54%',
> '77%',
> '70%',
> '100%',
> '61%'),
> ('Bedfordshire University', '81%', '42%', '77%', '58%', '57%', '61%'),
> ('Bolton University', '81%', '48%', '85%', '0%', '0%', '63%')...

Current output:

> ('Buckinghamshire New University', '78%', '39%', '82%', '0%', '0%', '52%'),
> ('Middlesex University', '82%', '48%', '80%', '57%', '75%', '54%'),
> ('City, University of London', '83%', '51%', '77%', '69%', '63%', '59%'),
> ('Goldsmiths, University of London',
> '85%',
> '54%',
> '77%',
> '70%',
> '100%',
> '61%'),
> ('University of Bedfordshire', '81%', '42%', '77%', '58%', '57%', '61%'),
> ('University of Bolton', '81%', '48%', '85%', '0%', '0%', '63%')...

The code to change the name of the strings works, it's just the matter of modifying the actual strings in the lists. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: can you share the content of your list?

Comment: Hint: if you write `a = (1, 2, 3)` and then `b = a[0]` and then `b = 'test'`, do you expect `a` to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign your value to `n`, but you never use `n` any further. Changing `n` does not change the value in the tuple in the list.

Instead you can create a new list and append each university to that with a new list containing the filtered values for each university. I've also taken the liberty to use more descriptive variable names.

```py
def filter_university_list(universities):
    filtered_universities = []

    for university in universities:
        current_university = []

        for field in university:
            if field.startswith('University of the '):
                field = field[18:] + ' University'
            elif field.startswith('University of '):
                field = field[14:] + ' University'

            current_university.append(field)
        
        filtered_universities.append(current_university)

    return filtered_universities
```